# Calling outer functions from required classes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Still getting to grips with node.js. I'm noticing that if classes are defined in the main js file, you can call functions that exist outside of the class from within the class.

```
function b(){
    console.log('b');
}
class X{
    a(){
        b();
    }
}

var c = new X();
c.a();
```

The above works fine, but if I make the class its own file using `require`, it tells me the function is not defined.

Main file:

```
var X = require('./X.js');
function b(){
   console.log('b');
}
var c = new X();
c.a();
```

X.js:

```
class X{
    a(){
        b();
    }
}
module.exports = X;
```

Why is this, and how do I get around it? Or is it poor practice to call outer functions from within the class?

Comment: It doesn't work because `b` isn't defined in a scope that's accessible by class `X`. Modules have their own scope.

Comment: And since modules have their own scope, the only way to get anything out of a module is by assigning to `module.exports`. So if `X.js` had another class `Y`, but it still had `module.exports = X;` at the end, then the main file wouldn’t be able to reference `Y` – only code inside `X.js` could reference it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a class outside of the file where it was described, you need to export it using `module.exports` or one of it's variants. E.g.:

file a.js:

```
function testClass(){
  console.log("Test class accessed on file a.js");
}
module.exports.testClass = testClass;
```

file b.js:

```
a = require('./a.js'); // check path to a.js

a.testClass();
```

EDIT:
Just a reminder, run `node b.js` and it should print `Test class accessed on file a.js`

Comment: If I did this, I'd have to write the function out twice; once in the main server and once in the class.

Comment: @ANON I thought that you wanted to call the class from another file, so yes, you have to declare the class on a file and call it from another one. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I want to call a global function from a required class. So there's a function called `b` in my main server, and in one of the required classes, there's a call to `b`, but it errors because it's not within the scope of the required class.